# Who manages the vim-scripts project on Github, and how is it used?

Tags: plugin-system, git

I'm referring to [this](https://github.com/vim-scripts).

Are there package managers that pull scripts from it by name? I ask because I notice that the version of my plugin contained in it is ***extremely*** old, and I'm wondering whether I should try to get it updated to the [latest version](https://github.com/bpstahlman/txtfmt).

Comment: I don't think that a) the project is maintained anymore, b) any plugin manager uses it.

Comment: I sent an email to the maintainer last February, who mentioned "gmarik has been running it...  I'll ping him.  If he's not interested, I should probably take it down." and then in a later email "gmarik just emailed that he'd look at it. It'll probably be back up tomorrow." ... Well, guess not :-) Apparently this is the reason it doesn't work: https://github.com/vim-scraper/vim-scraper/issues/78

Comment: @romainl The problem is that some plugin managers refuse to support anything other than git (*cough* vim-plug *cough*), so it's useful if you're not using git for an automatic mirror (I tried hg-git but that doesn't seem to work very well).

Comment: @romainl The following from Vundle's documentation is what makes me think it may still be used: 

Vim Scripts
-----------
Any single word without a slash '/' is assumed to be from Vim Scripts.
>
  Plugin 'ctrlp.vim' => https://github.com/vim-scripts/ctrlp.vim

Comment: @romainl @Carpetsmoker I noticed that Vundle appears to support both the github vim-scripts repo and vim-scripts.org. From the docs: "`Vundle` integrates very well with both GitHub and vim-scripts.org
(http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html) allowing short URIs." For plugin managers such as Vundle that support both, is there any advantage to continuing support for the github vim-scripts site?

Answer (score 2):

There are some technical problems which prevent the bot from running. See [#78](https://github.com/vim-scraper/vim-scraper/issues/78) for details on that. In addition in [#88](https://github.com/vim-scraper/vim-scraper/issues/88) one of the maintainers mentioned:

> Due to a lack of interested maintainers, right now we're discussing how to shut this project down... Should we delete everything? If not, how do we warn people that everything is stale and to use something else? Hoping to figure out a plan soon.

---

The bot has been broken since January 2016; almost a year and a half. And in that time no one seems to have cared enough to fix it. I wouldn't expect it to be fixed any time soon.

My way to fix this was to migrate everything from Mercurial/BitBucket to Github and then [write a rant about it](https://arp242.net/weblog/i-dont-like-git-but-im-going-to-migrate-my-projects-to-it.html). The fact is that for better or for worse, git/GitHub is the "de-facto" standard with some degree of "vendor lock-in".